# How to set link field href attribute to "#"

Tags: links, field

Using a general link field, I want to be able to author the field such that the final contents of an outputted link are:

`<a href="#">Anchor Text</>` (notice the empty anchor "#")

I'm rendering this field using the standard field renderer:

`@Html.Sitecore().Field("Field Name", someItem)`

The problem is that no matter how I author the field, I can never seem to get the `href` to populate with only `#`. Is there a way the link field can be authored to output only `#`?

- External links always append "http://" when I set the URL to be `#`
- If I try to use an anchor link and leave the anchor field empty, the `href` attribute remains empty
- If I try to use an anchor link and set the anchor as `#`, the `href` attribute has a value of `##`

Comment: Why do you want to set it do "#"? and should it _always_ be "#" or only when a content author specifies?

Comment: @RichardSeal Always "#" only when a content author specifies. I understand that this is a bit of a silly question, but I want to know if this will require a code intervention or if I can solve the issue with a minor content tweak.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Insert JavaScript` option

[image]

Specify *Link description* only (in your case 'Anchor Text')

**Example**

Field raw value

`<link text="Anchor Text" linktype="javascript" url="" anchor="" />`

HTML Output:

`<a href="#">Anchor Text</a>`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! As a side note, this will also automatically add `onclick="javascript:;return false;"` to the element.